# sql query for diff between rows

Tags: mysql, sql, date, rdbms

I have a table having dates in it, I would want to subtract the first date with the second, the second with the third and so on till the last n-1 with n.

How do I write a query for this?

The table would is called Random and the column name is date

```
 date       
+------------+
| 2009-06-20 |
| 2010-02-12 |
| 2012-03-14 |
| 2013-09-10 |
| 2014-01-01 |
| 2015-04-10 |
| 2015-05-01 |
| 2016-01-01 |
+------------+
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the next date.  I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.date,
       (select min(t2.date)
        from t t2
        where t2.date > t.date
       ) as next_date
from t;
```

You just need to use `datediff()` to get the difference in days.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER
For line numbering and then use a sub query to calculate the difference

```
SELECT  column_date 
,DATEDIFF( D , column_date 
,(SELECT column_date FROM
    (
    SELECT  column_date , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY column_date) AS RowMum
     FROM table_Random AS tBL_1
    ) AS tbl_2
       WHERE tbl_2.RowMum= tBL_1.RowMum-1
 )
         ) DIFF
FROM 
(
SELECT  column_date , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY column_date) AS RowMum
FROM table_Random
) AS tBL_1
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not notice the mysql tag when I wrote my answer first so am updating it now with link to MySQL 8.0 fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/myUJYeFrMXmU1piQXAmnv4/0

```
/* tested against MySQL v8.0 */
WITH T(d) AS (
    SELECT '2009-06-20' as d 
    UNION
    SELECT '2010-02-12'
    UNION
    SELECT '2012-03-14'
    UNION
    SELECT '2013-09-10'
    UNION
    SELECT '2014-01-01'
    UNION
    SELECT '2015-04-10'
    UNION
    SELECT '2015-05-01'
    UNION
    SELECT '2016-01-01'
), LAGGED(d, next_d) AS (
    SELECT d, LEAD(d) OVER (ORDER BY d ASC) AS next_d
    FROM T
)
/* datediff args are in opposite order to SQL server.  Also,
  only day part is considered */
SELECT l.d, l.next_d, DATEDIFF(l.next_d, l.d) AS n_days
 FROM LAGGED AS l
```

Here is my original answer that targeted SQL Server:

```
WITH T(d) AS (
  SELECT d FROM (
  VALUES 
  ('2009-06-20'),
  ('2010-02-12'),
  ('2012-03-14'),
  ('2013-09-10'),
  ('2014-01-01'),
  ('2015-04-10'),
  ('2015-05-01'),
  ('2016-01-01')
  ) AS T1(d)
), LAGGED(d, next_d) AS (
   SELECT d, LEAD(d) OVER (ORDER BY d ASC) AS next_d
   FROM T
)
SELECT l.d, l.next_d, DATEDIFF(DAY, l.d, l.next_d) AS n_days
FROM LAGGED AS l
```

and produces this output (modulo the fussy hand-editing I have done):

```
 
  d              next_d     n_days
  2009-06-20    2010-02-12  237
  2010-02-12    2012-03-14  761
  2012-03-14    2013-09-10  545
  2013-09-10    2014-01-01  113
  2014-01-01    2015-04-10  464
  2015-04-10    2015-05-01  21
  2015-05-01    2016-01-01  245
  2016-01-01    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I had not noticed the mysql tag. I updated my answer with a mysql-specific formulation.